# ServiceStack MemoryCached Authentication Register User

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm creating user service. Right now there can't be a normal repository system involved. I try to implement a authentication module for a single page app. Before i've written simply a mockup. The customer likes to see the default Auth Provider. Right now only a login service like `/auth/credentials` is required. But i need to register some users somehow to create a login page. Login seems quite simple. How can i create user? Is there any predefined route inside an provider?

```
POST on auth/credentials
{
    "UserName": "admin",
    "Password": "test",
    "RememberMe": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable the Registration Services to expose Services that allows creating a User with Password, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
        ...
    }) {
        IncludeRegistrationService = true
    });
```

The `IncludeRegistrationService=true` option enables ServiceStack's built-in [RegisterService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) which allows creating new users at `/register`.

You can find an example of this wired up in the [HttpBenchmarks Registration section](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#registration).